# SelectChannelConnector alternative class in Jetty 9 and above

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jetty

What is the alternative class of SelectChannelConnector for jetty 9 and above version? Also what is the use of SelectChannelConnector class? And also what is the use of connector classes in jetty/servlet architechture?

Can we use ServerConnector or NetworkTrafficSelectChannelConnector (deprecated in jetty 9.x) class instead of SelectChannelConnector?

Answer (score 5):

A `Connector` in jetty terms is the component that binds to a port, accepts incoming connections, negotiates the protocols (in case of SSL/TLS/ALPN and things like HTTP/2), and hands off the raw endpoint to the appropriate jetty internal component to process the request.

Gone are the days of listening on port 8080 and answering only in HTTP/1.x

Now you can listen on port 8080, and the incoming connection negotiates SSL > TLS > > ALPN > HTTP/2 (native) > HTTP/1.1 > HTTP/2 (h2c upgrate) etc.  Essentially picking the appropriate connection setup based on what both the client and the server can handle.

There is only `ServerConnector` left, and it has many configuration options to tell it what you want it to support.

See the embedded examples or the documentation to understand how to configure it.