# Setting up Jetty server

Tags: java, server, jetty

I use jetty-server and jetty-webapp packages with xml configuration but it shows an error:
**"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector"**

What does this error come from?

If comment this part of xml configuration:

```
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="port">8080</Set>
            <Set name="host">88.147.197.118</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>
```

then web-app starts without any errors.

The version of packages is 9.4.9.v20180320

Comment: Maybe the class was removed in jetty 9? Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788049/selectchannelconnector-alternative-class-in-jetty-9-and-above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector` is from Jetty 7.x and 8.x time period.  [Long ago deprecated and EOL.](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html).

The connector infrastructure in Jetty 9.x has changed dramatically since then. 
Mostly due to the pressures of SPDY and HTTP/2 (along with TLS/1.2 and ALPN).

Its rather out of scope to describe the entire new connector architecture in a Stackoverflow answer.

But if you are just looking for examples, I would suggest downloading the `jetty-home` artifact, or the `jetty-distribution` artifact an looking at the `/etc/*.xml` files for examples.

- jetty-home: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-home/
- jetty-distribution: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html

Look at:

- `jetty-http.xml` - for normal HTTP connector setup (HTTP/1.x only)
- `jetty-https.xml`  - for normal HTTPS (SSL/TLS) connector (HTTP/1.x only)
- `jetty-http2.xml` - for a typical HTTP/2 based connector with backoff to HTTP/1.1
- `jetty-ssl.xml` - for how to configure the SSL layer for HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

[SelectChannelConnector alternative class in Jetty 9 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788049/selectchannelconnector-alternative-class-in-jetty-9-and-above)

It seems that this class is not used with Jetty 9 and above. Use `ServerConnector` instead.

Comment: This should probably be in a community answer / wiki at this point eh?  Totally forgot about that prior answer.